# Converting a UNIXEPOCH timestamp stored in a database using SQLite3 in a bash script

Tags: bash, sqlite, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have an sqlite3 query

`SELECT DATETIME(ROUND(start_time / 1000), 'unixepoch') as Date FROM history`

When I open the database in dbbrowser,( **https://sqlitebrowser.org/** )the query runs fine.

I now try to run the command in a bash script.

`echo 'SELECT DATETIME(ROUND(start_time / 1000), 'unixepoch') as Date FROM history' | sqlite3 database.db`

The result is an error stating *no such column unixepoch*

I have also tried

`echo 'SELECT DATETIME(ROUND(start_time / 1000), 'unixepoch') FROM history' | sqlite3 database.db`

I've looked at the sqlite3 man page and can't see any usage for datetime.

Running

`echo 'SELECT start_time FROM history' | sqlite3 database.db`

will return the 13 digit unix epoch value  ie:1586107737232

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo 'SELECT DATETIME(ROUND(start_time / 1000), 'unixepoch') as Date FROM history' | sqlite3 database.db
# ...^..........................................^.........^......................^
```

This is a quoting error: you can't embed single quotes in a single quoted string. The "inner" quotes around "unixepoch" are being dropped.

Do this

```
echo "SELECT DATETIME(ROUND(start_time / 1000), 'unixepoch') as Date FROM history" | sqlite3 database.db
# ...^..........................................^.........^......................^
```

Comment: Oh my god.... I never noticed I was doing that... Thank you.
Also just realized I could have used:


 **date -d '1970-01-01 UTC + 1586107737232 seconds**

with the returned value.